# international character set EPSON Printer

Tags: epson

I am dealing with ESC/POS commands.

With `ESC R n`  command you can select an international character set.

Epson offers, among others: Spain II and Latin America. In those charsets, for example `Hex 5E/Dec 94`  means `"é" (LATIN SMALL LETTER E)`, but in UTF8/ISO `5E/94` means `"^" (CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT)`.

I am looking a way to translate those characters sets, or known their entire table (without looping and printing it through the printer, how do you know which is 'space'?)... It is not iso-8859-1/2/3/9 nor oem858/858 nor latin2/code page852  or similar charsets/codepages that I've checked.

Comment: Well finally I used ESC t and modified the character code table and not the international character set

Comment: how did you send character code command?

Comment: How did you resolve this ? Can you just help me out ?